# Replace a Wordpress Theme's .PHP file with a Short Code? Is This Possible?

Tags: php, wordpress

So this is the theme: http://themes.muffingroup.com/bretheon/   At the top is a slideshow. I just want to completely replace that slideshow with a google map instead, that is the same size. The map is responsive, so it will stay in that frame area. Im using Maps Marker Pro, its a google maps plugin, and it gives you a short code to embed the map on pages. But How would I embed it into that frame area of the slideshow?

The theme>editor file where the slideshows php code is, is called "header-offer-slider.php". (There could be additional files for its code, idk). But obviously just deleting that php code and pasting in the map shortcode for the google map does not work. Any idea how to do this?  You have to edit other .php files also right? Please be specific is possible.

This might help, here is a screenshot of the code, and the other .php files: http://s22.postimg.org/hd576h3g1/dasgfvdsafv.png

Thanks

---

TO Shomz below:

Im totally lost, I need more specifics, detailed.  So   I found a way to get the iframe code, but have no idea where to paste it in order to replace the themes slideshow with it. Do I delete ALL that  code in the  .php file, and paste the iframe code, do I just past it in a certain area? Multiple files? the .css file? What and where?

Thanks

Comment: Delete the slider wrapper and place the map instead.

Comment: Ahh, need way more info than that! So your saying, go into the themes .CSS file, and delete the div class of "slide-wrap slide-img"? Or just delete "<div class="slide-wrap slide-img">" from the .php file, and then what to replace with, etc...?

Comment: Well, with the amount of info you gave us, this is more than enough. :) Anyway, remove it from both (though only the HTML part will make a difference) and I guess take the iframe of the map and place it instead.

Comment: Its not an iframe, the map plugin generates a shortcode

Comment: How? Do you have an e--mail to reach you at? (if u dont mind?)

Comment: No, just update your question. Btw. if it's the WP template shortcode (`[something-here]`), that won't work out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, let's try it.

Your question is hard to answer because it's not about a specific error, but something much broader.

If you can get the iframe of the map with the proper looks and size that would fit your website, I'd remove the whole `mfn-offer-slider` div, and paste the iframe instead (or inside) of it. Optionally wrap the iframe with another div so you can style it easier. You can do that in the existing header, or make a new one and call it and use it appropriatelly (if you feel confident doing it).

Maybe the theme has an option to remove the slider completely, so you can use that instead (that way, you won't be hacking the theme and will be safe with updates).

Comment: Okay I got it, I pasted the iframe code below <div class="container">. Deleted everything under "<div class="container">". It looks fine , but Hopefully I didnt need any of the ending code huh?     Like this stuff:  " endif;
       ?>
      </div>
     
     </li>
     
    <?php 
     endwhile;
     endif;
     wp_reset_query();
    ?> 
   
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>"

Comment: No, no, don't touch the PHP stuff, if it looks good now, keep it like that.

Comment: Wait, dont touch it, as in dont delete it? or you mean go ahead and leave it deleted? Cause I already deleted it and it looks good. (Ill mark your answer as correct, thanks so much Shomz!)

Comment: If it's just some slider-related PHP (so it have both if and endif in **all** cases), then fine, leave it deleted. If it's something else, place it back in. It's so hard to help you without seeing what's going on, and I don't want to take you to a wrong direction.

Comment: Here, This will make it easier: http://justpaste.it/eomf      That is the exact code of the php file, and the BLUE text is what I deleted. But yeah, should be ok i think.

Comment: Looks like you deleted 2 divs too many (or not deleted 2 opening div tags), but the php part seems fine.

Comment: So it actually kinda messed up the site. lol. idk how to explain it without showing you....It screwed up the other sliders at the footer, ughhh   ....and what do you mean 2 divs to many?

Comment: The layout? Just make sure you fix those div issues. Delete the same amount of them before that opening ul tag as after the closing ul tag and it should be good.

Comment: idk what you mean div issues though? What ul tag? so what part do I need to fix?

Comment: The key ul is blue, the divs I'm speaking about are red: http://justpaste.it/eomj

Comment: OKay so I deleted the other 2 divs: <div id="mfn-offer-slider">
and <div class="container"> . The problem is I wanted to keep the container so the map stays within that area of the container, where the slideshow originally was. but maybe its just not possible, the map  will have to extend from end to end i guess

Comment: That's fine, you can keep them. Just make sure you remove the same number of them on the top and on the bottom in order to maintain the HTML structure.